# Rails high volume find_or_create and update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I process a bit of CSV files that are mostly `5MB` in size is about 20k rows or so.

currently to handle consistency our pattern is:

```
Chargeback.transaction do
  account.chargebacks
    .where(issue_id: row[:issue_id])
    .first_or_create!.update!(large_hash_of_new_state)
end
```

This is fine and it works, but is there a better way to just do something like:

```
Chargeback.transaction do
  account.chargebacks
    .where(issue_id: row[:issue_id])
    .insert!(large_hash_of_new_state)
end
```

not just code simplicity but less SQL too? is this an upsert?

Comment: The upsert would be dependent on your database.  Wanted to warn you that `first_or_create` suffers from a race condition as it literally does `first || create`.

Comment: database is postgres. i'm not worried about race conditions.

Comment: Take a look at postgres' "INSERT ... ON CONFLICT..." options. Good chance someone has written a gem to simplify it.